# spring-kafka ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplate Micrometer support

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, micrometer

we are using the

```
ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplate
```

in our Spring Boot application (Spring Boot 2.6.13) and want to see the producer metrics in the actuator endpoints. It does not seem to support this.
Any idea how I can setup the template to bind the metrics?
Spring-kafka version is 2.8.10

I found this code for the KafkaTemplate but the ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplate does not provide an option to pass a ProducerFactory.

```
    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> customProducerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().serializer().getClass().getName());
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().serializer().getClass().getName());
        DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
        producerFactory.addListener(new MicrometerProducerListener<>(meterRegistry));
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> customProducer() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(customProducerFactory());
    }
```

thx

Joachim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template is just a lightweight wrapper around `reactor-kafka`.

`reactor-kafka` does not use the spring-kafka `ProducerFactory`.

`reactor-kafka` does not currently support Micrometer at all.

Comment: What could be done for reactor-kafka to support Micrometer please?

Comment: There's an open issue https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kafka/issues/206 - contributions are welcome.